# React Hook useReducer always running twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I am loading data from a public API after my component is mounted. When the data is loaded I am passing it to the reducer, but it always fires twice. This is what I have:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   function reducer(data, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
         case 'INITIALIZE':
            return action.payload;
         case 'ADD_NEW':
            const newData = {...data};
            newData.info.push({});
            return newData;
      }
   }

   const [data, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, null);

   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(URL)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
               type: 'INITIALIZE',
               payload: response
            });
         })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
         });
   }, []);

   const addNew = () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD_NEW' });
   }

   return(
       <>data ? data.info.length : 'No Data Yet'</>
   );

}
```

As you can see the component awaits for the data to populate the reducer, which, when `INITIALIZE` is also called twice, but I didn't care about it until I needed to call `ADD_NEW`, because in that case it adds two blank objects into the array instead of only one. I wen't into the documentation for side effects, but I was unable to solve it.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: For one, try taking the reducer code out of the functional component

Comment: The effects run when the component is mounted. Unfortunately, in recent React versions, this can happen multiple times. If you use `<React.StrictMode />` then it will always happen twice (in development mode.) I am not aware of any good solution for that, it just sucks. You can use `useRef` to detect the first time it runs but when you use dependencies, things get really difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would deal with the issue.
The main reason why it was re-running the action effect was because you had the reducer in the component's function. I also went ahead and fixed several other issues.

The fetch code was a little off due to how fetch works. You have to get the data type off of the response which gives another promise instead of the data directly.

You also needed to make the rendering use {} to indicate that you were using javascript rather than text.

```
import React, { useReducer, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";
const url = `https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=3&limit=1`;
function App(props) {
  const [data, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(async response => {
        dispatch({
          type: "INITIALIZE",
          payload: (await response.json())
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const addNew = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_NEW" });
  };
  console.log("here");
  return (
    <>
      <div>{data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "No Data Yet"}</div>
      <button onClick={addNew}>Test</button>
    </>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
function reducer(data, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INITIALIZE":
      console.log(action.payload, "Initialize");
      return action.payload;
    case "ADD_NEW":
      const newData = { ...data };
      newData.info = newData.info || [];
      newData.info.push({});
      console.log(newData);
      return newData;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have reducer outside of the function component, but still facing the same thing. One dispatch call is resulting in two reducer case runs.

Comment: @SanchitKumar can you create that in a new topic? I can't debug something that I can't see.