# react hooks first dispatch causes other muplitple dispatch to fire twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Wherener I add more that one dispatch to `useEffect()` it causes all of the following to fire twice. Example below.

Here is the full code. Remove comments in any other order you want

ps. idk how to make it run as a code snippet

pps. I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071171/react-hook-usereducer-always-running-twice) as an example

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
const url = `https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=3&limit=1`;


function reducer(data, action) {
  console.log('reducer triggered', action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INITIALIZE":
      console.log(action.payload, "Initialize");
      return action.payload;
    case "ADD_NEW":
      const newData = { ...data };
      newData.info = newData.info || [];
      newData.info.push({});
      console.log(newData);
      return newData;
    case "INI2":
      return action.payload;
     case "INI3":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return
  }
}

function App() {
  const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //dispatch({type: "INI2"}); // uncommment this to get 2 reducer messages from each below
    console.log("here");  
    fetch(url)
      .then(async response => {
        dispatch({type: "INITIALIZE",payload: (await response.json())});
        //dispatch({type: "INI3"});  // uncomment this to see that every new dispatch is doubled after first one
      })
      .catch(error => {console.log(error);});
  }, []);

  const addNew = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_NEW" });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "No Data Yet"}</div>
      <button onClick={addNew}>Test</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a result of React.StrictMode being present in your App

According to the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the functions

And *Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer* are part of double invocation, which is why you see that behavior in your case

[Expected Working demo without React.StrictMode](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-violet-1e0lh?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Now I see. Thanks.
How do I disable it?

Comment: You need to remove <React.StrictMode> from your component hierarchy. If you used create-react-app, it must be in  index.js